# ggplot title and xlab() not working with variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So here is my code:

```
plotbmi <- function(variable) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(variable, bmi))+
  geom_boxplot()+
    labs(title = paste("BMI boxplot split up by", variable))
    ylab('BMI')+
    theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title =  element_text(size=14, hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'))
  return(plot)
}

plotbmi(data$region)
```

and my issue is that using this paste() in the title to concat the text with the variable is not working as I would like it to work. The plot title is not "BMI boxplot split up by regions"  but it's "BMI boxplot split up by northeast" (northeast is a possible value in the regions variable.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Instead of using `aes`, you can use `aes_string(variable, 'bmi')` and call your function as `plotbmi('region')`. An alternative is to use `aes({{variable}}, bmi)` and call your function as `plotbmi(region)`, but then you would need your `labs` call to be something like `labs(title = paste("BMI boxplot split up by", deparse(substitute(variable))))`. Of course, I can't test either of these options because we don't have your data - please make your questions reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation you're passing a character vector as the argument, which means it passes that vector itself to the `xlab` call. You can change this around to use `tidyselect` parts to both choose the correct column by column name and deparse it to paste in:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plotbmi <- function(variable) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes({{variable}}, group = factor(gear)))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    labs(title = paste("cars boxplot split up by",  rlang::get_expr(rlang::enquo(variable))))
  ylab('Gears')+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(plot.title =  element_text(size=14, hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'))
  return(plot)
}

plotbmi(cyl)
```

[image]